# Create a new column to indicate the trend on a particular column using pandas groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Session        ID       cumulative_prob
s1              1       0.4
s1              3       0.9
s1              4      -0.1
s1              5       0.3
s1              8       1.2
s1              9       0.2
s2              22      0.4
s2              29      0.7
s2              31      1.4
s2              32      0.4
s2              34      0.9
s3              36      0.9
s3              37     -0.1
s3              38      0.2
s3              40      1.0
```

From the I would like to create a new column which indicates the session wise trend (increase or decrease)

Expected Output:

```
Session        ID       cumulative_prob     Decrease
    s1              1       0.4             no
    s1              3       0.9             no
    s1              4      -0.1             yes
    s1              5       0.3             no
    s1              8       1.2             no
    s1              9       0.2             yes
    s2              22      0.4             no
    s2              29      0.7             no
    s2              31      1.4             no
    s2              32      0.4             yes
    s2              34      0.9             no
    s3              36      0.9             no
    s3              37     -0.1             yes
    s3              38      0.2             no
    s3              40      1.0             no
```

Note: Keep deafault 'no' for the first row for each Session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, [`GroupBy.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and [`np.where`](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-numpy-where/):

```
#import numpy as np
df['Decrease'] = np.where(df.groupby('Session')['cumulative_prob']
                            .diff()
                            .lt(0),
                          'yes',
                          'no')

print(df)
   Session  ID  cumulative_prob Decrease
0       s1   1              0.4       no
1       s1   3              0.9       no
2       s1   4             -0.1      yes
3       s1   5              0.3       no
4       s1   8              1.2       no
5       s1   9              0.2      yes
6       s2  22              0.4       no
7       s2  29              0.7       no
8       s2  31              1.4       no
9       s2  32              0.4      yes
10      s2  34              0.9       no
11      s3  36              0.9       no
12      s3  37             -0.1      yes
13      s3  38              0.2       no
14      s3  40              1.0       no
```

We can also use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
(df.groupby('Session')['cumulative_prob']
   .diff()
   .lt(0)
   .map({True : 'yes' , False : 'no'}))
```

Comment: If possible please look below question.. nobody answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463502/create-a-new-column-based-on-groupby-date-time-column-at-date-level-in-pandas

Comment: You don't really need `fillna(0).lt(0)`. `nan` is evaluated as `False` anyway.